# How to sample using Gibbs with a uniform latent variable?

Tags: conditional-probability, simulation, gibbs

I trying to sample using Gibbs from a proportional distribucion $f_{Z}(z)$:
\begin{align*}
 f_{Z}(z) \propto  e^{-z}\left(1-e^{-z}\right)^4, \quad z >0 
\end{align*}
using the joint $f_{Z,\textbf{U}}(z,\textbf{u})$
$$
f_{Z,\textbf{U}}(z,\textbf{u}) \propto  e^{- z} \prod_{i=1}^4 I_{\left(e^{-z}, 1\right)}\left(u_i\right)
$$
with $U \sim  U(0,1)$. I found that $p(U_i|Z,U_{-i}) \sim U(e^{-z},1)$, but i cant find $p(Z|\textbf{U})$.How should I sample from $p(Z|\textbf{U})$? it would depend on all the $u_i$ values? I got stuck on this.

Comment: This is a slice sampler, the whole point of uniforms is to replace challenging parts of the target with indicators. In the current case, a single uniform would have been enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $u_i$ has to be between $e^{-z}$ and $1$, then $e^{-z}$ needs to be between $0$ and $u_i$. Thus the distribution of $z$ given $\mathbf u$ is effectively a standard exponential RV with truncation:

\begin{align}
p(z|\mathbf u) &\propto e^{-z}\prod_{i=1}^4I_{(0, u_i)}(e^{-z}) \\
&= e^{-z}\prod_{i=1}^4I_{(\log(u_i), \infty)}(z) \\
&= e^{-z}\prod_{i=1}^4I(z > -\log u_i) \\ 
&= e^{-z}I(z > -\log u_{(1)})
\end{align}

where $u_{(1)} = \min (u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4)$. The easiest way to sample from this distribution is with a rejection sampler, with steps:

1. Sample $z^\star \sim Exp(1)$
2. If $z^\star > -\log u_{(1)}$, then accept. Otherwise return to step 1.

---

Verification of algorithm:

[image]

---

R Code:

```
# GIBBS SAMPLER
# Number of samples
M <- 10000 
# Initialize values
z <- rep(NA, M)
u <- matrix(NA, nrow=M, ncol=4)
z[1]  <- rexp(1)
u[1,] <- rexp(4)
# Begin sampler
for(m in 2:M){
  umin <- min(u[m-1,])
  # Sample z | u
  while(is.na(z[m])){
    zstar <- rexp(1)
    if(zstar > -log(umin))
      z[m] <- zstar
  }
  # Sample u_i | u_-i, z
  for(i in 1:4){
    u[m,i] <- runif(1, exp(-z[m]), 1)
  }
}

# MAKE FIGURE
fz <- function(z) exp(-z)*(1-exp(-z))^4
const <- integrate(fz, lower=0, upper=100)$value

hist(z, freq=FALSE, breaks=30)
curve(fz(x)/const, add=TRUE, lwd=2, col='orange')
```

Comment: ooh I couldn't see that condition to accept, thank you very much! :D